hardhat chai couldn't handle the revertedwith error
While trying to test the contracts, I couldn't able to catch the reason with reverted with statement.

        // Deploy the new USDT token
        const USDT = await ethers.getContractFactory('USDT1');
        const usdt2 = await USDT.deploy();
        const usdt2Address = await usdt2.getAddress();

        // move timestamp to one minute
        await ethers.provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [60]);
        await ethers.provider.send('evm_mine');

        expect(await usdt2.decimals()).to.equal(7);

    //    change the usdt token address in crowdsale
        expect(await crowdsale.changeUsdtToken(usdt2Address)).to.be.revertedWith('USDT token must have 6 decimals');
    });


Removing await made it to work.
expect(crowdsale.changeUsdtToken(usdt2Address)).to.be.revertedWith('USDT token must have 6 decimals');
